# nginx proxy_cache unable to cache

Tags: nginx, caching

ı trying content cache with Nginx but  not  working

that is my app.test.conf file

```
 proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=10g 
                 inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;
                 

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/app.test/html;
        index index.php;
        
        server_name app.test;
        
        proxy_cache my_cache;

        location / {
    
                
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I was able to solve it, reading started using fastcgi_cache instead of proxy_cache

Of course I added some more things

```
fastcgi_cache my_cache;
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 302 60m;
```

and result

```
fastcgi_cache_path  /var/cache/nginx/
                 keys_zone=my_cache:60m 
                 levels=1:2 
                 inactive=3h 
                 max_size=100m;

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/app.test/html;
        index index.php;
        server_name app.test;
    
       error_log /var/log/nginx/$host.log;
    
       fastcgi_cache my_cache;
       fastcgi_cache_valid 200 302 60m;

       fastcgi_cache_valid 404 1m;
    

    

        
    location / {
   
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
       
     }


    location ~ \.php$ {
     
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
     }

    }
```